# Programming Proportional Integrant in C

Tags: c

I'm doing my my project for a course and my goal is to implement the Proportional Integrant Control over a robot to track a line with 12 simple phototransistors. Now I've been reading many PID tutorials but I'm still confused. Can someone help me to start like from what I have been thinking...

I should assign each state of sensors a binary value and then use that in implementing the PI equation for error.... can some friend throw some light?

Comment: This is a feedback system, right? So where are you stuck? Do you know how to read the current state of the system? Do you know what the target state is? Do you know how to drive changes? Give us something to work with.

Comment: @dmckee,  its all there....in weird english, but its there :)

Comment: @dmc hehe my english is weak sorry...yes its a fb system.I know the target value (binary value) and can read the current state too from sensors.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the photo transistors are all in a line parallel to the front edge of your 'car', perpendicular to the edge of the track, and individually numbered from 0 - 11...

You want your car's center to follow the line.  Sensors #5 and #6 should straddle the line, and therefore be used be used as fine-tuning adjustment.  The sensors at the extreme ends (#0 and #11) should have the highest impact on your steering.

With those two bits of info, you should be able to set appropriate weights (multiplication factors) for your PI control to instruct your car to turn left a little, when sensors #7, #8 see the line, or turn left a lot when sensors #9, #10, #11 see the line.  The extreme sensors may also affect the speed of your car.

Some things to consider:  When implementing a front-wheel steering vehicle, it is often better to mount your sensor strip behind the front wheels.  Also, rear-wheel steering vehicles can adjust to sharp corners more quickly, but are less stable at high-speeds.

Comment: wow Thanks.Thats good enough to start up things...thanks a lot to you and everyother guy.this place is magic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the 12 sensors into a number from 1 to 12.   Then try and target a value of 6 in my PID.   Then use the output to drive the wheels.  Maybe normalize it so you get a +ve number means more right, and a negative means more left.

Comment: Oki Thanks .You mean i should implement the general flow of PI control and try to achieve the target which is the 3 sensors to be turned on. (00001110000)